# How to retrieve data for last 2 hrs from a specific Datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-date-functions

I am trying to extract last two hours records from a specific datetime. That means, I need to find out if there's any transaction occurred before `2019-11-20 18:00:00`. I have 100 records against which I need to extract 2 hrs prior activities.

Can I know how to formulate a sql query to fetch 2 hrs prior records?

This is how I was trying to formulate my code;

```
select distinct
    ID,
    START_DTTM,

from table1
where START_DTTM between dateadd(hour,-2,getdate()) and getdate();
```

I tried this `between  DATEADD(hour, -2 , CAST('2019-11-20 18:00:00' AS DATETIME)) and CAST('2019-11-20 18:00:00' AS DATETIME)`. returning only 20.

Also tried this; `WHERE START_DTTM > DATEADD(hour, -2 , CAST('2019-11-20 18:00:00' AS DATETIME)).` This one returns 200 records.

which one would be best approach.

Comment: use [dateadd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: you code seems fine -- what is your concern?  How speedy?  It is fine.  GETDATE() takes milliseconds

Comment: I need to hardcoded some specific "datetime". For example 2hrs of this dttm : "2019-11-20 18:00:00". How can I hard coded them? I have specific records which I need to validate.

Comment: just input the date time directly replacing the `getdate()`. Note : use format `YYYYMMDD HH:MM:SS`

Comment: @adey27 - You can try ```WHERE datetimecolum > DATEADD(hour, -2 , CAST('2019-11-20 18:00:00' AS DATETIME))```

Comment: @Roshan I've updated my queries. which one should I consider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very hard to answer this question because you don't tell us anything about the data model but if you want to get the last two hours of records and you have a column with a timestamp just add a where clause onto the select statement that says

```
 WHERE datetimecolum > DATEADD(hour, -2 , GETDATE())
```